# Is it possible to show all <select> <option>s as a toggle?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

This is a bit of a weird request, so I haven't seen any examples for it anywhere. Basically I want to 'unfold' a `<select>` so its options are visible, basically turning it into a toggle, of sorts. Here's my original `<select>`:

```js
        <span><input type="checkbox" className="onlyCheckbox" value={this.state.only} 
    onChange={this.handleOnlyChange.bind(this)} />
                              <label htmlFor="onlyIdentityBox">Only</label>
    <select value={this.state.operator} onChange={this.handleOperatorChange.bind(this)} >
                                    <option value="AND">AND</option>
                                    <option value="OR">OR</option>
                                  </select></span>
```

Ideally the solution would be css-only, but I'm not sure if that's possible (I've searched but not found any examples). Here's an image of what I'd like: [image: example.]

Is this doable?
edit: added context for the `<select>`'s surrounding elements.

Comment: this is can be done, but instead of select box, use checkbox.

Comment: Valid question, but I am just curious. Why would you want to show it as a toggle? You can as well have them as radio buttons rather than select options.

Comment: @RajaSekar you mean `radio` buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this with a select box is rather..... odd.  But sure it can be done.  This should be enough to get you started:

```css
.toggle{
  font-size:18px;
  height:1.4em;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  -moz-appearance:none;
  appearance:none;
}
.toggle option{
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  min-width:50px;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<select size='2' class='toggle'>
  <option value="AND" selected>AND</option>
  <option value="OR">OR</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Huh, that works perfectly in the demo. But in my page, I just get the rounded corners and it stays as a dropdown. I added some context for where it's placed in my OP.

Comment: did you include the `size='2'` attribute?

Comment: Aha, that was it, perfect :)

Addendum question; when I click the options they are blue, but when I click away the blue one turns to grey; I'd like the colour scheme to stay fixed regardless of whether it has focus or not.

Comment: Styling `:checked` options varies drastically browser to browser.  This is not something you are going to be able to do reliably.

Comment: Fair enough. Would this be easier as a pair of radio buttons (including the styling)?

Comment: Tried this in firefox and there's a 'third' option to the right of the 'OR' option which doesn't go away, so this may be better off done as a pair of radio buttons after all, to maximize styling compatibility.

Comment: whereas I TOTALLY agree that this should be done with radio buttons, you can fix the firefox issue by changing the width on the options to 50%.  I also set both box-sizing to border-box.  I made a few other tweaks in the above code for more consistency cross browser.

Answer (score 1):

If You can add some extra markup into your code then you can also try the following code:

Please check the fiddle for Demo. [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/p1bo7k1y/)

**HTML**

```
<select  id="select-box">
      <option value="AND" selected>AND</option>
      <option value="OR">OR</option>
</select>

<div class="toggle-effect">
   <label class="and">AND</label>
   <label class="or">OR</label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
select {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.and {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background:red;
  color: white;
}

.or {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background:blue;
  color: white;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.toggle-effect').on('click', '.and,.or', function(){
   var textInLabel = $(this).text();
   $('#select-box').val(textInLabel);
   $('#select-box').trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering around at CodePen I came up with this, I added some JS to add the scroll effect.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('select');

select.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

select.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e) {
  select.selectedIndex = select.selectedIndex + 1;
});
```

```css
select {
  overflow: hidden;
  size: 2;
  height: 18px;
}
option {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<select id="select" multiple>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```